# Formatting a string containing names (PHP/Regex)

Tags: php, regex, string, formatting

I am attempting to convert the following string:

```
1. WILL SMITH 2. ETO NABULI 3. WAQA BLAKE 4. WES NAIQAMA 5. DALLIN WATENE-ZELEZNIAK 6. TOM HUMBLE 7. LUKE CAPEWELL 8. SAM ANDERSON 9. KEVIN KINGSTON (C) 10. TIM GRANT 11. VAIPUNA TIA KILIFI 12. MATT ROBINSON 13. RYAN SIMPKINS 14. REAGAN CAMPBELL-GILLARD 15. KIERRAN MOSELEY 16. ANTHONY CHERRINGTON 17. TOM EISENHUTH 18. LIAM AYOUB
```

to this:

```
1. Will Smith
2. Eto Nabuli
3. Waqa Blake
4. Wes Naiqama
5. Dallin Watene-Zelezniak
6. Tom Humble
7. Luke Capewell
8. Sam Anderson
9. Kevin Kingston
10. Tim Grant
11. Vaipuna Tia Kilifi
12. Matt Robinson
13. Ryan Simpkins
14. Reagan Campbell-Gillard
15. Kierran Moseley
16. Anthony Cherrington
17. Tom Eisenhuth
18. Liam Ayoub
```

I have almost managed to get this to work but stuck on trying to capitalise the letter after the hyphen (i.e. Campbell-gillard) and handling names with two surnames (i.e. "Tai Kilifi"). Currently my attempt breaks with a three word name and the letter after the hyphen doesn't get capitalised.

This is my PHP code which POSTs the string from a simple html input field. My code now takes the string, removes the (C), searches for a number and names and places them into an array. Then formatted correctly. **I may be doing this in an over complex way, so any help will be welcomed.**

```
$string = $_POST['teamInput'];

$stringTeamFix = str_replace("(C)", "", "$string");
//Handles removing (C)/captain from string

preg_match_all("/\d+|[a-z'-]+/i", $stringTeamFix, $result);

if(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $stringTeamFix, $numbers)){
    $lastnum = end($numbers[0]);
}

$resultCount = count ($result[0]);

echo "<br/><br/>";

for ($a=0, $b=1, $c=2, $i=1; $i<$lastnum+1; $i++){

$firstName = $result[0][$b];
$surName = $result[0][$c];

$firstLower = strtolower($firstName);
$firstFix = ucfirst($firstLower);

$surnameLower = strtolower($surName);
$surnameFix = ucfirst($surnameLower);



echo $result[0][$a].". ".$firstFix." ".$surnameFix."<br/>";

$a+=3;
$b+=3;
$c+=3;
}
echo "<br/><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Zero-Width Replacement**

Do this:

```
$replaced = ucwords(preg_replace('~(?<!^)(?=\d)\b~', '\r\n', $yourstring));
```

The regex finds the position preceding the numbers (except the first), and inserts a line break.

- `(?<!^)` asserts that what precedes is not the beginning of the string
- `(?=\d)` asserts that what follows is a digit
- `\b` asserts that the current position is a boundary between word characters (digit, letter or underscore) and a non-word character

Comment: It's genius! Although, the only issue I have is trying to format the string into Title case (i.e. proper uppercase, including secondary uppercase after hyphen). I assume my previous calls to the multi-dimensional array can't be used now?

Comment: I tried ucwords and it mostly worked, but I did have to make the string lowercase first as I understand ucwords won't work if the string is uppercase when entered. The second name after the hyphen doesn't get capitalised. 

But I'll mark your answer has the working one as your regex was explained and very helpful.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I ended up using `mb_convert_case` to convert my string to title case, seemed to do the trick and made it simpler than trying to get `ucwords` to work with hyphened names

Comment: Good one, azsportza, thanks for sharing what you did. :)